# Jinja2: Compare items in one list to items in another list

Tags: python, list, compare, jinja2, items

I have a list of topics:

```
list1 = [topic1, topic2, topic3, topic4, topic5, topic6]
```

I would like to check another list against this list:

```
list2 = [topic2, topic4, topic6]
```

something like this:

```
{% if list2.items in list1 %}
```

where each item from list2 is checked for in list1. if all or any of the items from list2 are in list 1 then it's True. I figured this would be simple but I can't seam to find anything helpful about this.

Full example:

```
{% set list1 = [topic2, topic4, topic6] %}

{% for post in posts %}

   {% set list2 = [topic1, topic2, topic3, topic4, topic5, topic6] %}

   {% for topic in list2 %}
       {% if topic in list1 %}

          {# output of post list based on conditions #}

       {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

** I am working in a cms with out server side access so I only have the templating language to work with.

Comment: You can use list comprehension: `[item for item in list1 if item in list2]`

Answer (score 9):

Just create a custom filter:

```
def intersect(a, b):
    return set(a).intersection(b)

env.filters['intersect'] = intersect
```

And then use it as any other filter:

```
    {% if list1 | intersect(list2) %}
        hello
    {% else %}
        world
    {% endif%}
```

This is how it's done in [Ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/0274835adde81bd4e148e34f66e4379ba2427a31/lib/ansible/plugins/filter/mathstuff.py).

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any [Jinja2 built-in tests](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#builtin-tests) that can do this, but it's easy to add your own.

Let's say you have a template like this in a file called `template.j2`:

```
Is l1 in l2: {% if l1 is subsetof(l2) %}yes{% else %}no{% endif %}
```

You can then (in the same directory for this example), have a Python script that adds this check:

```
import jinja2


def subsetof(s1, s2):
    return set(s1).issubset(set(s2))


loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(".")
env = jinja2.Environment(loader=loader)
env.tests["subsetof"] = subsetof

template = env.get_template("template.j2")
print(template.render(l1=[1, 2], l2=[1, 2, 3]))
```

Note that the first argument of the test function is passed before the `is` clause in the template, while the second argument is passed within the brackets.

This should print:

```
Is l1 in l2: yes
```

Take a look at how to define custom tests [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/api/#custom-tests)

Comment: Good solutions! I am using a cms that only gives me a template language to work with though so I can't work with the python scripts.

Comment: Ah, in that case I'm not sure you can use a custom Jinja2 filter. You'd probably need to iterate over the items manually in the template. This wouldn't look as nice though, and the templating logic can only go so far.